# CSHTML/SQL SUM For A Row

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I know in mysql its SUM(size), but for some reason building this in razor cshtml its not the same and i cant find anywhere that talks about adding or subtracting 2 numbers in cshtml. So what would be the right function to use to add up rows size?

Code:

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Home @";
    var PageTitle = "Home";

    var db = Database.Open("PhotoGallery");
    var shows = db.Query(@"SELECT * FROM Shows").ToList();
    var seasons = db.Query(@"SELECT * FROM Seasons").ToList();
    var episodes = db.Query(@"SELECT * FROM Episodes").ToList();
    var comics = db.Query(@"SELECT * FROM Comics").ToList();
    var artists = db.Query(@"SELECT * FROM Artists").ToList();
    var albums = db.Query(@"SELECT * FROM Albums").ToList();
    var comicsize = db.Query(@"SELECT SUM(size) FROM Comics").ToList();   
    var totalsizeb = comicsize;
}

<h1>@PageTitle</h1>
<p align="center">
    @shows.Count TV Shows | @seasons.Count Seasons | @episodes.Count Episodes | @comics.Count Comics | @artists.Count Artists | @albums.Count Albums<br />
     Bytes |  MB |  GB |  TB
</p>
```

Error:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The specified argument value for the
function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = SUM ]
```

Comment: The exception is within `SqlServerCe` and doesn't look like it has to do with razor. You don't want to convert it `ToList()` because the result should be an `int`. (or other numeric datatype) `db.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT...")` would probably be more appropriate (not sure what framework you're using)

Comment: i downloaded webmatrix, and was just gonna use it for my php development, but then i noticed there was a cshtml file type in there and started exploring around last week with it.

Comment: It could also be that the column `size` does not exist in the `Comics` table.

Comment: i double checked it is there, and contains values like `435354` `5343212`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the `Count` of each table then you should `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Shows` and so forth rather than pulling all the data from each table just to get a count.

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Home @";
    var PageTitle = "Home";

    var db = Database.Open("PhotoGallery");
    var shows = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT Count(*) FROM Shows");
    var seasons = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT Count(*) FROM Seasons");
    var episodes = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT Count(*) FROM Episodes");
    var comics = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT Count(*) FROM Comics");
    var artists = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT Count(*) FROM Artists");
    var albums = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT Count(*) FROM Albums");
    var comicsize = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(size) FROM Comics");   
    var totalsizeb = comicsize;
}

<h1>@PageTitle</h1>
<p align="center">
    @shows TV Shows | @seasons Seasons | @episodes Episodes | @comics Comics | @artists Artists | @albums Albums<br />
      Bytes |  MB |  GB |  TB
</p>
```

`SUM` only works with numeric types such as `int`, `numeric`, `money`, and `float` make sure that the column is one of those types in your table.

Comment: Same Error: `System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = SUM ]`

Comment: Column `size` is set as `int`

Comment: easy mistake to make. In general, if you don't expect any null values, I'd remove "Allow Nulls" property from the column.

Comment: Now i want to break down `totalsizeb` to `totalsizekb`. Would this be correct? `var totalsizekb = totalsizeb/1024;` i tried it and it doesn't show anything after decimal places.

Comment: Would be funny if the result was actually a whole number. That should result in decimals but give this a shot `var totalsizekb = (double)totalsizeb/1024;`

Comment: there a way to limit it to 2 digits after the decimal place?

Comment: you are the man! you got a good link to the doc for this? i believe it is MVC3 right.

Comment: Well, everything in `WebMatrix` is `c#` so just the standard c# docs will work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xaz41263.aspx will give you all the math functions.

Comment: I got a new error now... `Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: Expression evaluation caused an overflow. [ Name of function (if known) =  ]` says the error is in this line `var episodesize = (int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(Size) FROM Episodes");`

Comment: Most likely the sum is too large to hold in an `int`, You can do this `SELECT SUM(Size) / 1024 FROM Episodes` to automatically return it in kb. or you can cast it to something else like `decimal` or `double`

Comment: none worked, i tried `(int)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(Size) / 1024 FROM Episodes");` `(double)db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(Size) FROM Episodes");` `db.QueryValue(@"SELECT SUM(Size) / 1024 FROM Episodes");` all still cause an overflow

Comment: Then your values, when added up, are probably too big to store in a single value. I would suggest you store kb or even mb instead of bytes. It's hard to see what's wrong without more access to the data.

Comment: For sure, i was thinking the values were too big, i'll just go swap it around to store the size in MB. the only problem is you cant store decimals into the int column :/